# Create iteration function to apply to a list of dataframes

Tags: r, function, for-loop, iteration, accumulate

I was wondering how to perform a recursive calculation over a list of dataframes? I have previously created a for loop that works but I would now like to convert this into a function that I can then apply to a list of dataframes. The equation that the for loop is based on is:

`api(i) = k * api(i-1) + rain(i)`

For loop example:

```
k <- 0.9                                    # assign k value
rain <- runif(n =50,  min = 0, max = 4)     # generate rainfall data
api <- numeric(length(rain))                # create api vector
api[1] <- k * rain[1]                       # set first api value

# for loop to calculate api
for (i in 2:length(rain)) {
  api[i] <- k * api[i-1] + rain[i]
}
```

Example data:

```
library(lubridate)
date_time <-
  seq(ymd_hm('2022-01-01 00:00'), ymd_hm('2022-02-01 23:45'), by = '15 mins')
precip <-  runif(n = length(date_time),
                 min = 0,
                 max = 4)
df1 <- data.frame(date_time, precip)

date_time <-
  seq(ymd_hm('2022-08-01 00:00'), ymd_hm('2022-09-01 23:45'), by = '15 mins')
precip <-  runif(n = length(date_time),
                 min = 0,
                 max = 4)
df2 <- data.frame(date_time, precip)

list_Df <- list(df1, df2)
```

I would like to assign the api object to a new column in each dataframe (e.g. `df$api`)

Thanks for your help!